# TCPDF not installing from composer in Zend Framework 2 project

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, tcpdf

I am trying to install TCPDF from composer. Here is the link of [package](https://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tcpdf). I have following contents in composer.json

```
{
        "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
        "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
        "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "zf2"
        ],
        "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1",
                    "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
                    "cgm/zf2-file-upload-examples": ">=1.0.0",
                    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
                    "gowsram/g-maps": "dev-master",
                    "ghislainf/zf2-whoops": "dev-master",
                    "nitecon/zf2-db-session": "1.*",
                    "ghislainf/geonames-server": "v0.9",
                    "aaron4m/zf2-static-pages": "dev-master",
                    "email-zf2/emailzf2": "dev-master",
                    "dkplus/crud": "dev-hotfix/6",

                    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
                    "zf-commons/zfc-admin": "dev-master",
                    "zendexperts/ze-theme": "dev-master",
                    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
                    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "dev-master",
                    "bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler": "dev-master",
                    "evandotpro/edp-module-layouts": "dev-master",
                    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
                    "mwillbanks/zfc-twitter-bootstrap": "dev-master",

                    "twig/twig": "~1.0",
                    "leafo/lessphp": "0.3.*@dev",
                    "leafo/scssphp": "dev-master",
                    "leafo/scssphp-compass": "dev-master",
                    "ptachoire/cssembed": "dev-master",
                    "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "1.*",
                    "hybridauth/hybridauth": "dev-master",
                    "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "dev-master",
                    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
                    "doctrine/common": "2.4.*@dev",
                    "doctrine/annotations": "1.0.*@dev",
                    "ircmaxell/random-lib": "1.0.*@dev",
                    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "0.5.*@dev",
                    "zendframework/zendpdf": "2.0.*@dev",
                    "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "2.0.*@dev",
                    "bjyoungblood/bjy-profiler": "dev-master",
                    "ocramius/ocra-service-manager": "dev-master",
                    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@dev",
                    "symfony/dependency-injection": "2.4.*@dev",
                    "symfony/http-kernel": "2.4.*@dev",
                    "doctrine/cache": "1.0.*@dev",
                    "monolog/monolog": "1.6.*@dev",
                    "danielss89/zfc-user-admin": "dev-master",
                    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "dev-master",
                    "darkmatus/roleuserbridge": "dev-master",
                    "neilime/zf2-twb-bundle": "1.0"
                    "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "dev-master"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
        }
```

}

When I run php composer.phar update, it always shows following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing tecnick.com/tcpdf (dev-master 6b842db)
    Cloning 6b842db6c4c42941c7233dc19fffa695f14d4000

[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The process timed-out.

How to fix this error? Or if there is any alternative way to include TCPDF in ZF2 project; if yes please provide some documentation about installation and usage as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the url repository with this lines :

```
**
"repositories": [
    {
         "type":"package",
         "package": {
         "name": "tecnick.com/tcpdf",
         "version":"master",
         "source": {
              "url": "http://git.code.sf.net/p/tcpdf/code", /* or something like that, it's the repo url*/
              "type": "git",
              "reference":"master"
         }
    }
],
"require": {
     ...
```

At the same level than 'require'

Answer (score -1):

In the previous code, we need close the package with a "}".

**In my case, I have fix it with adding the repositories like that :**

```
"repositories"     : {
    "sourceforge": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://git.code.sf.net/p/tcpdf/code"
    }
}, 
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    [...] Some others [...]
    "whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```